# google translation api character uses count

Tags: c#, asp.net

i recently purchased the google's translation API to convert from English to French. I have used the below URL to convert the data

https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=[My Key]&source=en&target=fr&q=hello

after getting response i checked the Traffic Reports for my project and noticed that
"Translate API: Translation Character Count" is increaed by 10 instead of 5.even i tried with other text also and its simply doubling my input characters. Not sure if this is the way my character use should be calculated?

i will appreciate if someone from google's API team can clarify my query.

Thanks,
Ritesh

Answer (score 1):

Google API is charged by the number of source characters

[Link](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq)

Comment: thanks for response.

This is what i also understood and that's why i assumed that the no. of characters used in above URL will be 5 i.e. for "hello" but api Traffic report count it as 10.